# Ramified covering of a 2-sphere punctured in k points

Tags: algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves

We are exploring a branched covering of a 2-sphere of order n. I was trying to calculate a $\pi_{1}(S^{2} \setminus \{t_1, ..., t_k\})$ and as I understand it is something like a $\langle \alpha_1, ..., \alpha_k | \ \prod\limits_{i = 1}^{k} \alpha_i\rangle$. Then we construct a set of permutations $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$ of base-point preimages. And now I have to prove these two properties:

- A subgroup of $S_n$, generated by $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$, acts transitievly on preimage set.
- $\sigma_k \ \circ \ ... \ \circ \sigma_1 = 1$

And there are things I cannot understand. If we define sigmas that way (by definition of monodromy): $\sigma_i (\tilde{x_j}) = \tilde{\alpha_i}(1)$, where $\tilde{\alpha_i}$ is lifting of  $\alpha_i$, s.t. $\tilde{\alpha_i}(0) = \tilde{x_j}, \forall \ i, j = \overline{1,k}$, then why must it be transitive action. I know, that for every $k = \overline{2, n - 1}$ there is a minimal generating system of $S_n$ with k generators, but there are no any conditions on k and n.
Perhaps, I am wrong in definitions or something

Comment: I am confused by your presentation of the fundamental group. The Sphere minus $k$ points is homotopy equivelant to the wedge of $k-1$ circles, so the fundamental group is free i.e. no relations. How did you obtain this presentation of $\pi_1$?

Comment: @Nick, I agree with you. For some reason I decided not to use S^n \ pt ~ R^n and got the relations from this: https://sun9-40.userapi.com/impg/14wq6ObhTTWRI7MzeCtDA2CaegqUjEwQirwLwg/bWJmdXHe6Z8.jpg?size=1600x625&quality=95&sign=d9c06199818ddc9cc7d2ea8c6e6a8376&type=album

Comment: Sphere minus a point is homeomorphic(stereographically) to  $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ which in turn is homeomorphic to the unit open disc ($\{x:|x|<1\}$) . So it is better to think of deleting $n-1$ points from an open unit disc. It is easy enough to find a single wedge point and deformation retract onto a wedge of $n-1$ circles. That being said, the fundamental group you have calculated is correct. It just means that for $\alpha_{n}$ you do not need an independent generator as it is expressible in terms of the $n-1$ generators. So it is indeed the free group on $n-1$ generators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that the set of permutations, which we have here, called a *constellation* and its transitive action on a set of n points doesn't mean that it generates $S_n$, because transitivity just means that there's a permutation for any two elements, which permutes one to another, and it doesn't have to be a transposition. At first we built a homomorphism $\phi :\pi_1(S^2 \setminus \{t_1, ..., t_k \}) \rightarrow S_n, \ \alpha_i \mapsto \sigma_i$ ($\sigma_i$ are defined as higher). Then an image of fundamental group is $G$.

So the first property is proved as follows: since covering space is linearly connected (this is assumed by default and I forgot to write it) we can connect each of n point with another one $\Rightarrow$ for each such way in covering space there's its image on a shpere and, therefore, in fundamental group $\Rightarrow$ there's such permutation from $G$.

Second property is obvious: $\sigma_1 ... \sigma_k = \phi(\alpha_1 ... \alpha_k) = \phi(1) = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Sphere minus a point is homeomorphic(stereographically) to  $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ which in turn is homeomorphic to the unit open disc ($\{x:|x|<1\}$) . So it is better to think of deleting $n-1$ points from an open unit disc. It is easy enough to find a single wedge point and deformation retract onto a wedge of $n-1$ circles. That being said, the fundamental group you have calculated is correct. It just means that for $\alpha_{n}$ you do not need an independent generator as it is expressible in terms of the $n-1$ generators. So it is indeed the free group on $n-1$ generators.

Here's a poorly drawn rough picture.

[image]

Comment: Anyway, I do not understand how do we bulid a monodromy from these generators, and since we have such conditions for sigmas I'd rather leave the fundamental group like I did